# Errors Using has_many :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I am trying to create a has_many :through association so that my Users can keep track of Domains by creating the association when they add them on their account page.

I have the following models:

models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  has_many :domain_followings, :foreign_key => "domain_id"
  has_many :domains, :through => :domain_followings
```

models/domain_followings.rb

```
class DomainFollowings < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :domain_id

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :domain
end
```

models/domain.rb

```
class Domain < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :domain_followings, :foreign_key => "user_id"
  has_many :users, :through => :domain_followings
```

I get errors like the following in my specs:

```
   1) Users signup success should make a new user
     Failure/Error: click_button
     NameError:
       uninitialized constant User::DomainFollowing
     # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:32:in `show'
     # ./spec/requests/users_spec.rb:32
     # ./spec/requests/users_spec.rb:26
```

The code in question is here:

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @title = @user.name
    @domain = Domain.new if signed_in?
    @domains = @user.domains.paginate(:page => params[:page])
  end
```

The uninitialized constant User::DomainFollowing is repeated several times for other code.
Ideally I would like my code to require a user association in the domain_followings table before allowing a domain to be created in the domain table.  Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think it's related, but I'm puzzled about the `:foreign_key` declarations for the instructions `has_many :domain_followings` in User and Domain. It seems to me that they're inverted (and if it's not on purpose, it should be removed).

Comment: That was causing problems saving the relationship.  I also had problems because the relationship's model was plural rather than singular.  I Fixed these things, and it's working better but there are still issues with a lot of the functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to rename the relationship model to models/domain_following.rb, making it singular.  Also removed foreign_key declarations following Bladrick's suggestion.  Everything flows smoothly now.